# Как разобрать строку по разделителям?

Tags: javascript, строки, vue.js

С бэка прилетает массив строк с разделителями в виде запятой:

```
{'DATA': [
'word_A, word_B, word_C', 
'word_A, word_B, word_C',
'word_A, word_B, word_C'
]}
```

как разделить строку и каждое слово присвоить отдельной переменной?

Comment: это не валидный json. Или это все одна строка?

Comment: @НазарКалитюк верно, ошибочка. Поправил.

Comment: да все равно, если json, то не правильный

Comment: @НазарКалитюк Еще раз внес изменения

Comment: А почему слова повторяются?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин потому что они повторяются

Comment: то есть `word_A` должен попасть в три переменных?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Нет. Хотелось бы в цикле сделать вывод. Три переменных. Вывод в табличку или в span

т. е.
var_a = word_A
var_B = word_B
var_c = word_C

Comment: Товарищ намекает на то, что в json строковые литералы всегда в двойных кавычках.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы разделить строчку используем [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

```js
var str = 'word_A, word_B, word_C';

/* разделяем через разделитель запятая */
var array = str.split(",");

/* убираем лишние пробелы в конце и начале */
array = array.map(x => { return x.trim(); });

console.log(array);
```

Comment: все здорово. Но как это в секцию <tempate> добавить и выполнить вывод там?

Comment: @Alex Надо использовать `v-for`. сделать два цикла, внешний для генерации строк и внутренний для генерации ячеек.

Comment: При этом данные хранить в массиве массивов (двумерный массив), и в циклах обращаться к ним через `data[i][j]`

Comment: Все верно. Вопрос закрыт. Спасибо!