# Разбить строку в массив по первому пробелу

Tags: javascript, массивы, строки

Есть строка, допустим `'Вот такая вот строка'`, как её разбить по первому пробелу, чтобы получить вот такой массив `['Вот','такая вот строка']`?

Comment: а это задача jQuery? Почему нет тега JS?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/string#vzyatie-podstroki-substring-substr-slice

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разобрать строку по разделителям?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/797684/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc)

Comment: @Dmitriy, вообще не дубликат. Сравните вопросы, схожесть только в том, что в обоих случаях массивы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, отдельно разбить первый элемент массива (*"Вот"*) c помощью *split*, остальное уже без него вторым элементом.

```js
let str = 'Вот такая вот строка';
let result = [str.split(' ', 1).toString(), str.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ')];

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var tests = [
  "Вот такая вот строка",
  "Вот",
  " такая вот строка",
  "",
];

for (var s of tests) {
  console.log(s.match(/^[^ ]*|(?<= ).*/g));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log('Вот такая вот строка'.replace(/\s+/, '\x01').split('\x01'));
```

Comment: Бррррррррррр :(

Comment: @Qwertiy, хдддд

Answer (score 1):

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let text = document.getElementById("text");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

let f = str => {
  let part2 = str.replace(/^.*?\s/g, "");
  let part1 = str.substr(0, (str.length - part2.length - 1));
  return [part1, part2];
}

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let val = text.value;
  let res = f(val);
  result.value = JSON.stringify(res);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</textarea>
<button id="btn">Click</button>
<textarea id="result"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = 'Вот такая вот строка'.match(/([а-яА-Я\w]+)\s(.*)/).splice(1);

console.log(result);
```