# input type file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как перебрать в jquery картинки из массива

есть код

```js
$(function() {
  function readURL(input) {
    $(input.files).each(function(i, el) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).appendTo('#im');
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
    });
  }

  $("#imgInput").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" name="bn" id="imgInput" multiple>
<div id="im"></div>
```

при загрузке каждой фото мне нужно вставить в li

```
<ul class="ai_image__list ui-sortable" id="sortable" rotation="0">                            
        <li class="ai_image__upload"></li>
        <li class="ai_image__upload"></li>
        <li class="ai_image__upload"></li>
        <li class="ai_image__upload"></li>
        <li class="ai_image__upload"></li>
</ul>
```

вот например я удалил из списка одно изображение, то мне нужно удалить и в общем img[], а если я вместо удаленного новое добавил то присоединить

Comment: исправил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поддерживает выбор нескольких картинок сразу.

```js
let input = document.getElementById("input");
let ul = document.getElementById("ul")

input.addEventListener("change", e => {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < e.srcElement.files.length; i++) {
    let file = e.srcElement.files[i];
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    li.append(img);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      img.src = reader.result;
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
});
```

```css
ul>li>img {
  width: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" accept=".jpg,.jprg,.png" multiple>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: Misha Saidov, ты зря удалил свой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925293/Разбить-строку-в-массив-по-первому-пробелу

Comment: @Air почему? Был же дан более изящный ответ

Comment: Любой ответ хорош. Каждый ответ несет в себе что-то новое и интересное...Даже если вдруг твой ответ не совсем верен, кто-то из сильнейших сделает тебе замечание подправит... И ты осознаешь свою ошибку...

Answer (score 2):

`FileList` у `input` только для записи. Поэтому вместо манипуляций с ним предлагаю использовать отдельный массив, куда добавляются выбранные файлы.
При клике по списку элемент удаляется и из списка и из массива.

```js
(function() {
  const inputImage = $('#input-image');
  const imagesList = $('#images-list');
  const images = [];

  inputImage.on('change', changeHandler);

  function changeHandler(e) {
    addImage(e.target.files[0], imagesList);
  }

  function addImage(image, parent) {
    images.push(image);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const item = $('<li>').attr('key', images.length);
    item.appendTo(parent);
    item.on('click', itemClickHandler);
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('<img>').attr('src', e.target.result).appendTo(item);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(image)
  }

  function itemClickHandler(e) {
    const item = ($(e.target).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() === 'img') ?
      $(e.target).parent() :
      $(e.target);

    images.splice(item.attr('key') - 1, 1);

    $(item).remove();
  }
})()
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input-image" type="file">
<ul id="images-list"></ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```